# Xcode 11.3.1 with Firebase

Tags: swift, iphone, gtmsessionfetcher

I've been making an Xcode app. When I run it on the simulator it works. When I run it on my iPad it also works but when I try to use is on my iPhone 11, it doesn't work. Gets the following message:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

And in the console:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher
>     Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B50AD250-D857-4C76-B9BB-EC8377913E91/WBG.app/WBG
>     Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B50AD250-D857-4C76-B9BB-EC8377913E91/WBG.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B50AD250-D857-4C76-B9BB-EC8377913E91/WBG.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B50AD250-D857-4C76-B9BB-EC8377913E91/WBG.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: stat() failed with errno=25
>       /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B50AD250-D857-4C76-B9BB-EC8377913E91/WBG.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B50AD250-D857-4C76-B9BB-EC8377913E91/WBG.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B50AD250-D857-4C76-B9BB-EC8377913E91/WBG.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: stat() failed with errno=1
>       /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B50AD250-D857-4C76-B9BB-EC8377913E91/WBG.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B50AD250-D857-4C76-B9BB-EC8377913E91/WBG.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher'
>
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B50AD250-D857-4C76-B9BB-EC8377913E91/WBG.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher: stat() failed with errno=1

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the libary *GTMSessionFetcher* is not copied on your device. PLease check on Your **Project target settings**, under section **Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content** that you have chosen *Embed & Sign* or *Embed Without Signing*.

Alsom, one of the issues might be that library GTMSessionFetcher was built for iPad Architecture only when archived.
Check sample image below
[image]

Comment: Did you check the Target Membership and flag? When you select the framework on the right part there should be checkmark to add or remove framework from target membership. Be sure that it is ticked.

Comment: where can i find it? tnx a lot

Comment: On the left panel in Xcode, under section Frameworks, select the framework which crashes from your logs - GTMSessionFetcher, after that select right panel in Xcode and you will see Target Membership section. Be sure that the flag is ticked for your app.
In general, you crash logs indicates that when you are running the app on the device, the framework is not copied and runs only locally on the machine/simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same problem... It got fixed by adding:

In you podfile:

`use_modular_headers!`

instead of

`use_frameworks!`

Good luck! I hope this works for you!